# BOOL not saving in User Defaults

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Can someone please help me understand why this bool isn't saving?

Here is my code in the view did load:

```
[appDelegate.defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"testKey"];
[appDelegate.defaults synchronize];
NSLog (@"TEST BOOL VALUE = %@", [appDelegate.defaults boolForKey:@"testKey"] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

In the app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching, I define appdelegate.defaults as this:

```
    self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Why is this not working I honestly have no idea.

Thanks!!

Comment: What type of property are you using to store `defaults`?  Assign?

Comment: How did you declare the `defaults` property? What happens when you replace `appDelegate.defaults` by `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: nonatomic retain.I'm going to try replacing it with the NSUserDefaults and see what happens. Check right back

Comment: ya the user defaults totally worked. Thats weird tho because I've been using the defaults successfully with the app delegate property in many other locations. Hmmm

Comment: How is `appDelegate` declared and when do you set its value? See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appDelegate` is `nil` when you are calling the mentioned code.

Try adding an `NSSlog` to check that:

```
NSLog(@"appDelegate: %@", appDelegate);
NSLog(@"appDelegate.defaults: %@", appDelegate.defaults);
[appDelegate.defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"testKey"];
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"testKey"];
```

Or setting the `defaults` property to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`